# Set a new Variable in Assemble (or combine two comparison helpers)?

Tags: html, handlebars.js, assemble

is there a way to set a new variable in a partial in assemble (assemble.io)? Or is it possible to combine two comparison-helpers, for example:

```
{#is somevar "yes" || anothervar "no"}
```

There's HTML in my partial which should only be shown if one of two different variables is true. If there's only one variable, i only write `{{#is somevar "yes"}}`, but i need that `#is`-helper for both variables.

I haven't found a way in the assemble-docs so i tried another way. I tried to do two `#is`-Helper like:

```
{{#is somevar "yes"}}
  // HTML
{{/is}}
{{#is anothervar "no"}}
  // HTML (the same as above)
{{/is}}
```

But this is really redundant... so i tried to set a variable inside both #is, for example:

```
{{checkvar = 0}}
{{#is somevar "yes"}}
  {{checkvar = 1}}
{{/is}}
{{#is anothervar "no"}}
  {{checkvar = 1}}
{{/is}}
```

So i only have to check for one variable (`checkvar`).

BUT all this wont work... So is there a way to do this in assemble?

Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be something common to any Handlebars templates and not specifically Assemble.

Assemble uses [handlebars-helpers](https://github.com/assemble/handlebars-helpers/) and we've recently upgraded to Handlebars 3.0 so you can use a combination of [subexpressions](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html#subexpressions) with the `or` and `is` helpers:

```
{{#or (is somevar "yes") (is anothervar "no")}}
  <div>somevar = yes or anothervar = no</div>
{{/or}}
```

Edit: This might not work since the `is` helper is a block helper. You might have to write your own helper to just return the value. Either that or change `somevar` and `anothervar` to be truthy values instead of `yes` and `no`. Then you can just use the `or` helper directly:

```
{{#or somevar anothervar}}
{{/or}}
```

Comment: This is exactly what i did, i wrote my own helper, seems there's no other way, but thanks for your answer! :-)